# How do i format a USB as EXT4 from Mac

Tags: mac, ext4

I'm creating a small script for my java Application to run. However, there is no way that I can find to format a USB to ext4. How do I do this from the command line? I'm on macOS Ventura and want a simple way to do this.

I tried using ext4fuse, but unfortunately, It doesn't work because apple disabled kernel extensions.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need an ext4 USB stick for your application to run? What exactly have you already tried to to format and write to an ext4 partition?

Comment: It's an application for linux related stuff, i dont want to be too exposive of it. i tried using ext4fuse, but unfortunately it doesn't work.